# Galleria JS not working in production with Rails pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, galleria

I'm running Galleria.IO's JavaScript gallery in my rails app, and everything works fine in development, and in production on pages where I specifically include the Galleria code. But when you hit a page that doesn't have the code, it keeps throwing errors like

```
No theme CSS loaded
Fatal error: Theme CSS could not load after 20 sec. Please download the latest theme at http://galleria.io/customer/
```

I've included the galleria files in my pipeline:

```
// application.js
//= require galleria.min
//= require galleria.classic.min

/* application.css
*= require galleria.classic
*/
```

The following does in fact initialize the gallery correctly on pages where there is a `#galleria` element, but throws the above error everywhere else:

```
if ($("#galleria").length == 1) {
        Galleria.loadTheme('/assets/galleria.classic.min.js');
        Galleria.configure({
            debug: false,
            // imageCrop: true,
            dummy: '/assets/fallback/large_default.png',
            transition: 'fade'
        });
        Galleria.run('#galleria');
    }
```

Is there a way to have the theme loaded automatically in the asset pipeline instead of having to separately initialize it?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you should just ALWAYS load a theme!

Put the following in app/assets/javascripts/galleria_setup.js:

```
    Galleria.loadTheme('/assets/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.configure({
        debug: false,
        // imageCrop: true,
        dummy: '/assets/fallback/large_default.png',
        transition: 'fade'
    });
```

Then change your manifest to

```
// application.js
//= require galleria.min
//= require galleria.classic.min
//= require galleria_setup
```

Then when you want to actually fire up:

```
if ($("#galleria").length == 1) {
    Galleria.run('#galleria');
}
```